# issue with image object in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am complete newbie in **fabric.js**. I need to load several images from URL in canvas and add them as image object so I can set their z index.

I tried using `Image.fromURL` but it did not return object so I can't set their z index. New `fabric.Image` take images from page so I am not getting results from it.

This is what I have done so far

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
var front_wall = fabric.Image.fromURL('img/bedroom1-front/front_wall.png', 
    function(img) {
        img.scale(0.65);
        canvas.add(img);
    }
);
```

I add five more images same way.

Can `fabric.Image.fromURL` return the image object (by using any attribute) ?

So I can change their z-index after loading.

Sorry I don't have **jsfiddle** to show.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, since you're aware that you don't follow conventions and rules, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Thank you for reply, i will read and follow the rules. Can you please help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJ9MC/159/)

I added some comments in that fiddle. Code is below:

```
var srcImg = "http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg";
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var icon = null;
var image = fabric.Image.fromURL(srcImg, function(oImg) {
                    oImg.set({width: oImg.width / 3,
                              height: oImg.height / 3,
                              left: 100,
                              top: 100,
                              originX: 'center',
                              originY: 'center',
                              selectable: false,
                              transparentCorners: false});

          //magic strats here to make active Image and you can control image object here
                    canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                    icon = canvas.getActiveObject();
                    icon.hasBorders = false;
                    icon.hasControls = false;                   
                    canvas.add(oImg);
                });

//if you want to control outside somewhere you can do this:
setTimeout(function(){
    icon.set({'top': 200, 'left': 200});
  canvas.renderAll();
}, 1500);
```